# Best community for SVG developers?

Tags: svg, forum

I am really struggling with finding a community devoted to all things SVG. There are all kinds of places and forums for JS, RoR, PHP and now the buzz with HTML5 canvas but where is the love for SVG?

I have read some insightful responses from STackoverflow members like 'Echoflow' & 'Erik Dahlström' on few things SVG but Im hoping to discover a wider community as well. Any guidance?

Cheers,

Comment: This queston was asked way back in 2010. Now, in 2014 we all know that SO is the world's best programming community. No need to look elsewhere ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one of the main forums for interest in SVG development is the svg-developers yahoo group: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/svg-developers/